Why does the PHP spread operator in an Elasticsearch query return different results than hardcoding parts of the query?
I've got a problem that I'm not entirely sure I understand. I've got the following Elasticsearch query, written in PHP, with fuzziness matching hardcoded; this results in about an expected 1,500 search results.
private function phraseQuery(array $matchFields): array {
        return [
            'bool' => [
                "minimum_should_match" => 1,
                "should" => [
                    $this->multiMatch($matchFields),
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'Title' => [
                                'query' => $this->searchTerm,
                                'fuzziness' => 'AUTO:4,8'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ], [
                        'match' => [
                            'TransliteratedTitle' => [
                                'query' => $this->searchTerm,
                                'fuzziness' => 'AUTO:4,8'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

When I replace the 'match' parts of my query to dynamically generate with a function I get 4 exact search results; Elasticsearch effectively seems to ignore the fuzziness queries. I have confirmed on PHP Playground that the queries are structurally exactly the same, but there appears to be a difference between the two queries. Does the PHP spread operator not work in this way?
private function fuss(array $matchFields): array {
        $fuzziness = [];
        foreach($matchFields as $field) {
            $query = ['query' => $this->searchTerm , 'fuzziness' => 'AUTO:4,8'];
            $match = [ $field => $query ];
            $fuzziness[] = [ 'match' => $match ];
        }
        return $fuzziness;
}

private function phraseQuery(array $matchFields): array {
        return [
            'bool' => [
                "minimum_should_match" => 1,
                "should" => [
                    $this->multiMatch($matchFields),
                    ...$this->fuss($matchFields),
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

Any help is much appreciated!
FYI: I'm using Elastic Cloud and PHP v8
I have tested my code on PHP playground to make sure the queries to Elasticsearch are structured in the exact same way. I have run both forms of query and one returns 4 results and the other nearly 1,500.

In your original code, there's a nested array containing the match terms. Using the spread operator puts them at the same level, not nested. Don't use ...

Try [...$this->fuss($matchFields)] to have it as an array, not every value as a single parameter.

Thanks for the replies so far. @Barmar; in the original they are at the same level (an array with three entries) and that query works properly: multimatch => ..., match => ..., match => ... etc. @Markus Zeller: no luck! As far as I know the query should be at the same level.

Ah, you're right, I misread it.

Try using var_dump() to view the result of calling phraseQuery(), and compare it to a correct array.

Thanks Barmar, I ran it through the Symfony Var_Dumper and found the solution was actually in how the names of the fields were generated; nothing wrong with the actual spread operator. I'll post the correct solution below. Thanks again!

With the help of Barmar I found the solution was in the way fieldnames were generated.
At first glance both arrays used Title and TransliteratedTitle field names, but Barmar suggested to read the output of phraseQuery itself and that showed that in one function I passed in Title and TransliteratedTitle as fieldnames for the match and in the other (non-working) function Title^100 and TransliteratedTitle^100 (the ^100 is part of providing a weight to ElasticSearch).
The correct solution is therefore:
"should" => [
   $this->multiMatch($matchFields),
   ...$this->fuss($matchFields),
]
etc.

Elasticsearch thus effectively did ignore fuzziness queries on two non-existent fields, Title^100 and TransliteratedTitle^100.
